# Is there a size limit for the SQL text in a PeopleSoft App Engine SQL Step/Action?

Tags: sql, peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

I'm getting the following error: AeSymResolveStatement [775] ... Meta-SQL error at or near position 34338 in statement (108,512).  The SQL statement itself is over 40,000 chars long, hence the question.

The DB is oracle. Running on Tools 8.49.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such limit.

You can confirm this yourself by creating an SQL like:

```
select 'x' from PS_INSTALLATION where 
      1 = 1 and 
      1 = 1 and
      1 = 1 and
      1 = 1 and
      /* ... copy paste '1 = 1 and' 90000 times or so times more */
      1 = 1
```

Although it makes pside quite slow, It saves and validates just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I know that there is a limit on the size of the SQL used in an Application Engine (SQL Step). I had once recieved a similar error while trying to use an exceptionally long SQL in an Application Engine.

I wouldn't be surprised if that same limit applies to SQL Objects.

To fix the problem, I was able to split the SQL into 2 (was an update statement). Hopefully that's possible in your case as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are limits within PeopleCode, mostly due to the limits on string length, however I have never found a limit on stored SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd look at breaking the statement into pieces in some way.

You could:

- Using the inbuilt looping mechanism of App Engines
- Use a mixture of SQL and PeopleCode
- Use a temporary table and perform intermediate SQLs, storing in the temp table

Apart from giving your database a heart seizure, not the mention the DBA when he sees the statement in the SQL monitor. You are saving yourself a world of pain if you ever have to look at the statement again.

I think the SQLs in App Engines are stored as longs, so it would be 4GB under Oracle, something similarly huge under DB2.